# Exception to fix javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException exception

Tags: jakarta-mail, transport

I am learning how to send an email with javamail API, i have created the necessary properties and instructions to send a simple email using SMTP server, and i am using this code :

```
     Properties props=new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session= Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

    protected PasswordAuthentication getpPasswordAuthentication(){
    return new  PasswordAuthentication("myemailadresse@gmail.com", "password");
    }


    });
    try{
        Message message=new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail"));    
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("recepientemailadresse"));
        message.setSubject("the java mail test");
        message.setText("Guess what brother the java mail is working correctly");
        Transport.send(message);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "message sent");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and i the run time an exception occurred mentioning that :

```
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:329)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at transfer.Maitest.jButton1ActionPerformed(Maitest.java:96)
at transfer.Maitest.access$000(Maitest.java:20)
at transfer.Maitest$1.actionPerformed(Maitest.java:45)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
```

would you tell me what did i miss please  ??

Answer (score 1):

First, read this [JavaMail FAQ entry about common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  After correcting them, read this [JavaMail FAQ entry that tells you how to connect to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  If it still doesn't work, this [JavaMail FAQ entry about debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) will help.

Answer (score 0):

If your email server does not require authentication and you don't want to supply a password (for example, test environment), try this:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
```